# c# interop.word - printout - randomly changed printer settings

Tags: c#, printing, ms-word, interop, office-interop

I'm having a really weird problem with Interop.

I developed a small program that opens a **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application** and use it to prints documents:

```
object[] oWordDialogParams = { printerName, true };
string[] argNames = { "Printer", "DoNotSetAsSysDefault" };
object wordBasic = wordApplication.WordBasic;
try
{
  wordBasic.GetType().InvokeMember("FilePrintSetup"
  , BindingFlags.InvokeMethod
  , null
  , wordBasic
  , oWordDialogParams
  , null
  , null
  , argNames);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  Logger.Instance.Log("failed to set printer");
}
doc.Activate(); 
wordApplication.PrintOut(Background: ref backgroundPrint, FileName: ref sourceFile);
```

Everything works fine pretty always (I would say 95% of the times), I'm able to see the correct print queue and, most important, the printer settings are **the default printer settings** (i.e.: nothing happens in the printer preferences):

[image: ok]

But, in a few cases, the document is passed to the printer without the extension (docx in this case) **and the printer setting are changed (for example the paper size is set to letter)**:

[image: notok]

Please note that:

- in my code the *FileName: ref sourceFile* is always correctly set with the extension, but (randomly!) it appears in the print queue without the extension. **When this happens it means also that the printer settings are changed to something not default**.
- the exact same document reprinted works fine (!)

I'm working with:

- framework 4.0
- interop 12.0
- windows server 2008 R2
- the printer uses the HP Universal Print Driver

Thank you all for your precious help!

Comment: Word document can have individual settings for printing which are overriden if set. If you open Word, and go to File > Print > Page Setup > Paper (tab) this is which the Paper Size settings is set. These settings can also be found in the object model under Document.PageSetup. As for the extension, i am not sure what is going on with that.

Comment: I already check these settings and they are correct. Moreover, the same document reprinted prints fine!